# Как сделать выезжающий ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Добрый день.
Ситуация такая: eсть `Grid` с двумя колонками разделенными `GridSplitter`. В первой колонке есть `ListView`, у которого бывает горизонтальный `scroll`. Необходимо что бы по нажатию по кнопке `ListView` менял свою ширину на заданную и как бы "выпадал" из потока и становился поверх всех.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я просто явно задаю `Width`, то естественно у меня все съезжает как тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы `ListView` перекрывал при расширении остальные столбцы в сетке надо:

- установить `Grid.ColumnSpan=3`(в зависимости сколько вы хотите перекрыть)
- установить `Grid.ZIndex=2`(больше остальных)

Я сделал так:

задаем нашу сетку

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
     <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

сразу добавим `SpliterGrid`:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="5"                     
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></GridSplitter>
```

в первую колонку заносим `ScrollViewer` (вы сказали что `ListView` имеет горизонтальный скролл)

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding ColumnSpan}" 
              Grid.ZIndex="2"> <!--важный момент, индекс больше чем у содержимого второй колонки -->
      <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="{Binding WidthListView}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Поле1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Поле2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Поле3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Поле4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Поле5" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding }"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Поле6" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding }"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
      </ListView>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

В эту же колонку добавим кнопку отвечающую за расширению `ListView` (кнопку можно добавить по желанию в любое место)

```
<Button Grid.Row="1"                
            Width="100" Height="20"
            Command="{Binding StretchCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateListView}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="сжать"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateListView}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="расстянуть"/>
                </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

во вторую колонку что угодно.

```
<Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.ZIndex="1">Content</Label>
```

`MainVM`:

```
    //ширина ListView
    public int _widthListView=100;
    public int WidthListView
    {
        get { return _widthListView; }
        set { _widthListView = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("WidthListView"); }
    }

    //количество перекрываемых столбцов
    private int _columnSpan = 0;
    public int ColumnSpan
    {
        get { return _columnSpan; }
        set { _columnSpan = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ColumnSpan"); }
    }

    //состояние ListView true-расширена false - сжата
    private bool stateListView = false;
    public bool StateListView
    {
        get { return stateListView; }
        set { stateListView = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("StateListView"); }
    }


    //команда которая расширяет/сжимает ListView
    private DelegateCommand _stretchCommand;
    public ICommand StretchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_stretchCommand == null)
            {
                _stretchCommand = new DelegateCommand(stretchingExecute);
            }
            return _stretchCommand;
        }
    }

    private void stretchingExecute()
    {
        if (!stateListView)
        {
            WidthListView = 350;
            ColumnSpan = 3;
            StateListView = true;
        }
        else
        {
            WidthListView = 100;
            ColumnSpan = 0;
            StateListView = false;
        }

    }
```

Вот что у меня получилось:
[image: результат]